# Interesting function with geo

Tags: geometry, functions

For which pairs $(m,n)$ does there exist an injective function $f:\mathbb{ℝ}^2→\mathbb{ℝ}^2$ under which the image of every regular polygon with $m$ sides is a regular polygon with $n$ sides?

That is probaly a realy hard problem. I love solving functions, but I haven’t solved functions in geometry. I don’t have any idea. Please help!